# Go doesn't release memory after http.Get

Tags: http, memory-leaks, go

I am loading web pages using simple thread pool, while dynamically loading urls from file. But this small program slowly allocate as much memory as my server has, until omm killer stops it. It looks like resp.Body.Close() doesn't free memory for body text (memory size ~ downloaded pages * avg page size). How can I force golang to free memory allocated for body html text?

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

func worker(linkChan chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

    for url := range linkChan {
        // Getting body text
        resp, err := http.Get(url)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Fail url: %s\n", url)
            continue
        }
        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        resp.Body.Close()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Fail url: %s\n", url)
            continue
        }
        // Test page body
        has_rem_code := strings.Contains(string(body), "googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js")
        fmt.Printf("Done url: %s\t%t\n", url, has_rem_code)
    }
}

func main() {
    // Creating worker pool
    lCh := make(chan string, 30)
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)

    for i := 0; i < 30; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go worker(lCh, wg)
    }

    // Opening file with urls
    file, err := os.Open("./tmp/new.csv")
    defer file.Close()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    reader := bufio.NewReader(file)

    // Processing urls
    for href, _, err := reader.ReadLine(); err == nil; href, _, err = reader.ReadLine() {
        lCh <- string(href)
    }

    close(lCh)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Here is some output from pprof tool:

```
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
   34.63MB 29.39% 29.39%    34.63MB 29.39%  bufio.NewReaderSize
      30MB 25.46% 54.84%       30MB 25.46%  net/http.(*Transport).getIdleConnCh
   23.09MB 19.59% 74.44%    23.09MB 19.59%  bufio.NewWriter
   11.63MB  9.87% 84.30%    11.63MB  9.87%  net/http.(*Transport).putIdleConn
    6.50MB  5.52% 89.82%     6.50MB  5.52%  main.main
```

Looks like [this issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/5794), but it's fixed 2 years ago.

Comment: What version of Go are you using?

Comment: (probably not related, but `lCh` isn't buffered, so queueLen will always be 0)

Comment: Modified lCh initialization, now queueLen calculating properly, but memory growth still here.

Comment: Shot in a dark, but if you save a substring/subslice of the body in a global, that would keep the entire string/slice "alive" from the GC's perspective.

Comment: Get a stack trace from when the process has accumulated a lot of memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/I2c7wO0SR3I) on golang-nuts. `http.Transport` saves connections for future reusing in case of request to same host, causing memory bloating in my case (hundreds thousands of different hosts). But disabling KeepAlives totally solves that problem.

Working code:

```
func worker(linkChan chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

    var transport http.RoundTripper = &http.Transport{
        DisableKeepAlives: true,
    }

    c := &http.Client{Transport: transport}

    for url := range linkChan {
        // Getting body text
        resp, err := c.Get(url)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Fail url: %s\n", url)
            continue
        }
        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        resp.Body.Close()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Fail url: %s\n", url)
            continue
        }
        // Test page body
        has_rem_code := strings.Contains(string(body), "googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js")
        fmt.Printf("Done url: %s\t%t\n", url, has_rem_code)
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing some of the other defaults from `http.DefaultTransport` that may be useful to you, like the Dialer with a timeout. Also, if you are often making requests to the same hosts too, you may want to have keepalives, and periodically use Transport.CloseIdleConnections instead.

Comment: Sure, in actual code I am also using `Dialer` with timeout, but it irrelevant to solution, so I decided to skip this part. As all my requests going to different hosts, using `Transport.CloseIdleConnections` makes no sense right now, but may be useful sometime. Thank you!